# Getting the count() of a column from a resulting query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem where when getting the results of a query on the product_view table I would also like to get the total number of product months (from the product_month column) for each month related in the query results.

### For example

If I did a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product_view
WHERE product_price BETWEEN 945 AND 980;
```

and the product_view table had the data like this:

```
INSERT INTO product_view
    (`product_id`, `product_month`, `product_price`)
VALUES
    (4, 'DEC', 999),
    (4, 'FEB', 905),
    (4, 'JAN', 905),
    (8, 'DEC', 1049),
    (8, 'FEB', 955),
    (8, 'JAN', 955),
    (8, 'DEC', 1049),
    (8, 'FEB', 955),
    (8, 'JAN', 955),
    (22, 'APR', 925),
    (22, 'AUG', 969),
    (22, 'JUL', 969),
    (22, 'JUN', 945),
    (22, 'MAR', 925),
    (22, 'MAY', 925),
    (22, 'OCT', 915),
    (22, 'SEP', 945),
    (27, 'APR', 1435),
    (27, 'JUN', 1459),
    (27, 'MAY', 1435),
    (27, 'OCT', 1459),
    (27, 'SEP', 1459),
    (31, 'APR', 3029),
    (31, 'AUG', 3029),
    (31, 'FEB', 3029);
```

I would not only want the statement to give me the results of the query, but also the total count() for each month in the results returned. i.e. using the query above - FEB = 2, JUN = 1 etc...

**End result - with duplicates count() results**

```
PRODUCT_ID  PRODUCT_MONTH   PRODUCT_PRICE   Month_count
8               FEB          955            2
8               JAN          955            2
8               FEB          955            2
8               JAN          955            2
22              AUG          969            1
22              JUL          969            1
22              JUN          945            1
22              SEP          945            1
```

Please could someone advise me on the best way to get the count() from the results and also is there a better way of showing these mulitple counts **without the results of it being duplicated on each row in the query's result set**. i.e. variables, or temporary tables (though with temp tables there are many users executing this query simultaneously, so would there be problems with getting accurate results per user as the product_price BETWEEN values of the above query can be changes by the user)

Thanks

Comment: can u please show us ur desired output.so that we can suggest the query accordingly.

Comment: So what do you want in the end result? You will repeat the data in columns for as many rows you are fetching. Either you send two queries (one with GROUP BY  and COUNT), and the other that returns the results; or you calculate the totals on the application end.

Comment: @RishabhRaj I have added the end result to the question. I want the query results to be shown as above. Though I would like to also know if there is a better way to display the query results with the each month count being shown.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I suppose I could do two queries instead of it all being in one. How would I go about calculating the month counts on application end? Are you suggesting that I calculate it on the application domain ie. java, c# .net?

Comment: Yes, and if you are going to be hitting this query a lot, cache the results.

Comment: @Fazz. Were you able to accomplish what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY product_month:

```
SELECT product_month, COUNT(*)
FROM product_view
WHERE product_price BETWEEN 945 AND 980
GROUP BY product_month;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8248d/2)</kbd>

This will give you:

```
PRODUCT_MONTH   COUNT(*)
AUG                 1
FEB                 2
JAN                 2
JUL                 1
JUN                 1
SEP                 1
```

Comment: All I had to add to this answer was was the product_id field. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

i think u should use group by.have a look at the following query.

```
SELECT product_month,count(product_month) as month,sum(product_price)
FROM product_view
WHERE product_price BETWEEN 945 AND 980
group by(product_month);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total sales of a product per month

```
select product_id, product_month from product_view 
group by product_id, product_month;
```

Result

```
product_id  | product_month
4           | JAN
4           | FEB
14          | JAN
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use query below:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_MONTH, PRODUCT_PRICE, COUNT(*)
FROM product_view
WHERE product_price BETWEEN 945 AND 980
GROUP BY PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_MONTH, PRODUCT_PRICE;
```